# You do not have permission to view this directory or page. ASP.CORE

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have a Asp.Core Application hosted by App Service and we enable Azure Active Directory for the Authentication.

Do you know why after authentication we have this error :

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page. azure asp core

Thank you

Comment: Have you double-checked the permissions on the folders where the project is hosted?

Comment: How ? In the portal or AzureDevops ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can access the website without enabling Azure Active Directory. If you can, check the redirect url.

It should be

```
 https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

Comment: Exactly. I disable the Authentification/Authorization in the App Service and everything is working fine. But Why do i need to disable this control in App Service ?

Comment: @Julien I just suggest that you disable it to test if your website work. When you encounter that error message, what is the url?